# Export and Import Functions in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export, react-component

I'm creating a webapp that uses react. I have a main `App.js` file that serves as the main component. I then have a subcomponent that has functions that create buttons. For example, I have a `renderLogoutButton()` that contains a logo, text, etc.

I need the logout button in a different subcomponent and don't want to have to duplicate the function. How can I export the `renderLogoutButton()` from one React component and import it into another React component?

All help is appreciated; thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Are you using Node?

Comment: Yes; I'm using node

Comment: Google for "node import export" and you should be all set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move your `renderLogoutButton` code to a seperate `LogoutButton` component, you can re-use the component wherever you want without code duplication.

This will also shrink the size and complexity of your `App` component, which is preferable.